# Apache CXF Enum gives jaxbexception

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I have created a CXF webservice and all methods works except the methods where an argument is a Enum. I've generated my javaclient code using the wsdl2java command.

```
public enum OrderDirection {
    DESC, ASC;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

When I try running, for example, getAllUsers(orderBy, OrderDirection.DESC); I get a exception:

```
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.tdr.wsclient.OrderDirection nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
```

The wsdl definition for the OrderDirection Enum looks like this:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="orderDirection">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="DESC"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="ASC"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a error in my interface. I had in an acid trip defined my Enums like this:

```
List<User> getAllUsers(String orderBy, Enum<OrderDirection> direction);
```

it should be like this:

```
List<User> getAllUsers(String orderBy, OrderDirection direction);
```